# Appending functions results within a for loop

Tags: r

Not a reproducible example, but here is my problem. I have a data frame and am looping through a series of columns and performing forecasting. I've created a fuction that will handle the forecasting part as it's repetitive and place it within the for loop. So each iteration of the loop, the forecast_func loop will be used to perform the forecast and accuracy assessment, and rbind those results to the results data frame.

```
result = data.frame()
forecast_func = function(data){
    data.train = rnorm(100)
    data.test = rnorm(10)
    library(forecast)
    mod = auto.arima(data.train)
    mod_forc = forecast(mod)$mean
    mod_acc = accuracy(mod_forc, data.test)
    result = rbind(result, data.frame(mod_forc))
}
result

for(i in ...){
  ...
  forecast_func(data)  
  ...
}
```

If I were doing this once, I know how to append the results to result. However, within a for loop, every time I use the function, I get an empty data frame. Obviously, it's not returning to the global environment. However, I was wondering what were some useful strategies for attaching this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the parent assignment operator here (`<<-`):

```
forecast_func = function(data){
    data.train = rnorm(100)
    data.test = rnorm(10)
    library(forecast)
    mod = auto.arima(data.train)
    mod_forc = forecast(mod)$mean
    mod_acc = accuracy(mod_forc, data.test)
    # assign to 'result' data frame in the parent (calling) scope
    result <<- rbind(result, data.frame(mod_forc))
}

result = data.frame()

for (i in ...) {
  ...
  forecast_func(data)  
  ...
}
```

This being said, using the parent assignment operator is usually frowned upon, based on what I have seen here on SO and elsewhere.

One way to avoid having use `<<-` would be to refactor your `forecast_func` to return a data frame, instead of trying to persist the result internally:

```
forecast_func = function(data){
    data.train = rnorm(100)
    data.test = rnorm(10)
    library(forecast)
    mod = auto.arima(data.train)
    mod_forc = forecast(mod)$mean
    mod_acc = accuracy(mod_forc, data.test)

    return(data.frame(mod_forc))
}

result = data.frame()

for (i in ...) {
  ...
  # just rbind() here in the calling scope
  result = rbind(result, forecast_func(data))
  ...
}
```